# What is wrong this this typo3 flow migration code and new domain? I get sql errors when I try to migrate

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, migration, typo3-flow

What is wrong this this typo3 flow migration code and new domain?  I get sql errors when I try to migrate.  Seems like a simple new domain, it will allow me to define a new product type - a Kit - that will be defined as having components drawn from other products - in my plain old SQL thinking the resulting table is just a couple of foreign keys (one to the kit product and one to the sku (a collection of product items) from which a component product is drawn) and a quantity field to say how many items to draw from the respective sku, and of course many rows can link to the same product to indicate that a given kit can be made of numerous types of products.

The new Domain:

```
<?php

namespace SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model;

/* *
 * This script belongs to the TYPO3 Flow package "SeeThroughWeb.Shop".    *
 *                                                                        *
 *                                                                        */

use TYPO3\Flow\Annotations as Flow;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * A Kit
 *
 * @Flow\Entity
 */
class Kit {



    /**
     * The product  
     * @var \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Product 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $product ; 

    /**
     * The product article
     * @var \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\ProductArticle
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $productArticle;

    /**
     * The quantity
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $quantity;




    /**
     * The creation date
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $creationDate;




    /**
     * The Constructor for Kit
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->creationDate = new \DateTime();
        $this->quantity = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Get the Kit's product article
     *
     * @return \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\ProductArticle The Kit's product article
     */
    public function getProductArticle() {
        return $this->productArticle;
    }

    /**
     * Sets this Kit's product article
     *
     * @param \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\ProductArticle $productArticle The Kit's product article
     * @return void
     */
    public function setProductArticle($productArticle) {
        $this->productArticle = $productArticle;
    }

        /**
     * Get the  product  
     *
     * @return \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Product  The   product  
     */
    public function getProduct () {
        return $this->product ;
    }

    /**
     * Sets this Kits product 
     *
     * @param \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Product  $product The kits product 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setProduct ($product ) {
        $this->product  = $product ;
    }


    /**
     * Get the Kit's quantity
     *
     * @return integer The Kit's quantity
     */
    public function getQuantity() {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Sets this Kit's quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity The Kit's quantity
     * @return void
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity) {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }



}

?>
```

The migration code:

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your need!
 */
class Version20150105162605 extends AbstractMigration {

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema) {
        // this up() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");

        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_kit (persistence_object_identifier VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, product VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL, productarticle VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL, quantity INT NOT NULL, creationdate DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_3E2E11A6D34A04AD (product), INDEX IDX_3E2E11A69975A841 (productarticle), PRIMARY KEY(persistence_object_identifier)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_kit ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3E2E11A6D34A04AD FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_product (persistence_object_identifier)");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_kit ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3E2E11A69975A841 FOREIGN KEY (productarticle) REFERENCES seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_productarticle (persistence_object_identifier)");
    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema) {
        // this down() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");

        $this->addSql("DROP TABLE seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_kit");
    }
}
```

The migration attempt produces this :

```
Uncaught Exception
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE
  seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_kit ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3E2E11A6D34A04AD
  FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_product
  (persistence_object_identifier)':

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
  'shop_epiexpert.#sql-611c_66d3' (errno: 150)

More Information
  Exception code      #0
  File                /home/epiexpert/domains/shop.epiexpert.com/public_html/releases/20131219160416/Packages/Libraries/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 47
```

The new table however **does get created** and looks ok in mysql workbench.  I'm guessing there is something wrong in the @ORM choice but not sure what, I have tried some others but so far no luck, I'm very new to Doctrine and Typo3-Flow.

Thanks

Addendum 1: resulting table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_kit` (
  `persistence_object_identifier` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `productarticle` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creationdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`persistence_object_identifier`),
  KEY `IDX_3E2E11A6D34A04AD` (`product`),
  KEY `IDX_3E2E11A69975A841` (`productarticle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

which looks right to me, so why the errors?  Are those keys right?  is there some other table getting created to support them?  could there be  a permissions/privilege  problem?
And when I enter that Alter table command in mysql workbench I get the same error.

and here is the create table for product:

```
CREATE TABLE `seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_product` (
  `persistence_object_identifier` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primarycategory` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdby` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(4095) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creationdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `facebookpublish` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitterpublish` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isfeatured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryofmanufacture` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issenderproducerindicator` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `availableregion` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`persistence_object_identifier`),
  UNIQUE KEY `flow_identity_seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_product` (`name`),
  KEY `IDX_7AF89F541C52F958` (`brand`),
  KEY `IDX_7AF89F54B99DBC88` (`primarycategory`),
  KEY `IDX_7AF89F5446D262E0` (`createdby`),
  KEY `IDX_7AF89F541FEA467` (`countryofmanufacture`),
  KEY `IDX_7AF89F54AE3174AD` (`availableregion`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7AF89F541C52F958` FOREIGN KEY (`brand`) REFERENCES `seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_brand` (`persistence_object_identifier`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7AF89F541FEA467` FOREIGN KEY (`countryofmanufacture`) REFERENCES `seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_country` (`persistence_object_identifier`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7AF89F5446D262E0` FOREIGN KEY (`createdby`) REFERENCES `typo3_flow_security_account` (`persistence_object_identifier`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7AF89F54AE3174AD` FOREIGN KEY (`availableregion`) REFERENCES `seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_currency` (`persistence_object_identifier`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7AF89F54B99DBC88` FOREIGN KEY (`primarycategory`) REFERENCES `seethroughweb_shop_domain_model_productcategory` (`persistence_object_identifier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I use MariaDB 10 and recently I came across exactly the same issue. 

Not sure about the root cause, but from the `CREATE TABLE` statement, I removed the part `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` and left only `ENGINE = InnoDB`.

Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, tried it but no luck.  Exact same error messages.  Table still gets created too despite the "Can't create table" message.

Comment: Please note Addendum 1

Comment: AHA!!   The collation alone was the problem,  I removed the `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` but kept the `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8` and `ENGINE = InnoDB` and the  migration ran without error.

Comment: and according to mysql workbench the product and productarticle columns still have `Collation:  utf8_general_ci` anyway.